# Add onclick event to div in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to add a onclick event to a  tag, but it isn't working. Can anyone tell me the correct way to add an onclick to this tag in js?

```
  var cell = result.appendChild(document.createElement('abbr'));
  cell.title = "cell number 1";
  cell.className = 'chart-cell-type'; 
  cell.addEventListener='onclick',(alert("clicked!"));  //broken
```

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you're more specific than "isn't working", both in what behavior you want and what you expect.

Comment: I think you need to look into the basics of JavaScript syntax a little bit more. `addEventListener` is a method that takes two parameters, a string and a function.

Comment: @Jeffery: the onclick event isn't being added to the element.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Alexis points out, your syntax is wrong. You want something like:

```
cell.addEventListener("click", function() {alert("clicked");})
```